# psql -h IP/localhost -U postgres -W/-w is not working

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to connect to postgres DB using the following 2 commands and it fails to connect to DB :

- psql -h 10.x.x.x -U postgres -W
- psql -h localhost -U postgres -W

Output:

```
-bash-4.2$ psql -h 10.x.x.x -U postgres -W
Password: 
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "10.54.48.59" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
-bash-4.2$ 
-bash-4.2$ psql -h localhost -U postgres -W
Password: 
psql: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"
-bash-4.2$
```

But when I try to connect to DB using the command without IP, it works:

```
-bash-4.2$ psql -U postgres -W
Password: 
psql (11.3)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

I tried by having the following list in my pg_hba.conf as well :

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            password
```

Comment: I have looked at the solution presented for that question , but my issue is not resolved by that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try...

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
```

and then

```
psql -h localhost -U postgres DB
```

Comment: Just tried that, didn't work, same error was observed:
`-bash-4.2$ psql -U postgres -d postgres -h localhost 
psql: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"
-bash-4.2$`

Comment: @Madh your OS ?

Comment: The OS I am using is RHEL 7.7